# Samba and WSDD and still no happiness sharing with Windows 10 and Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: networking, windows-10, lts

I followed (I think) the instructions in [this post](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1071523/how-to-get-my-ubuntu-shared-folders-appearing-under-network-in-windows-10/1148490#1148490) and removed the "User" and "Group" from `/etc/systemd/system/wsdd.service` file and installed the latest Samba and added a user to it. It was the same name and password as used in Windows 10.

I edited the SMB.CONF to share my NTFS formatted disks like this:

```
[P-1800]
path = /media/darrell/P-1800
writeable = yes
force user = darrell
```

[and three more shares]

Global settings changed as:

```
workgroup = WORKGROUP
force user = darrell
client max protocol = NT1
```

and I think I added the "security = user" to the Global Definitions section.

After making the changes, I did `sudo systemctl restart smbd nmbd` and started WSDD as `/usr/bin/wsdd -4 -v &` and got:

```
2020-01-18 17:14:08,471:wsdd WARNING(pid 3097): no interface given, using all interfaces
2020-01-18 17:14:08,471:wsdd INFO(pid 3097): using pre-defined UUID 2e59ba01-7d42-5a44-a9ef-8d0e740f77ff
2020-01-18 17:14:08,477:wsdd INFO(pid 3097): joined multicast group ('239.255.255.250', 3702) on 192.168.1.128%enp4s0
2020-01-18 17:14:08,484:wsdd INFO(pid 3097): 192.168.1.124 - - "POST /2e59ba01-7d42-5a44-a9ef-8d0e740f77ff HTTP/1.1" 200 -
2020-01-18 17:14:08,484:wsdd INFO(pid 3097): 192.168.1.123 - - "POST /2e59ba01-7d42-5a44-a9ef-8d0e740f77ff HTTP/1.1" 200 -
2020-01-18 17:14:08,485:wsdd INFO(pid 3097): 192.168.1.120 - - "POST /2e59ba01-7d42-5a44-a9ef-8d0e740f77ff HTTP/1.1" 200 -
2020-01-18 17:14:08,486:wsdd INFO(pid 3097): 192.168.1.120 - - "POST /2e59ba01-7d42-5a44-a9ef-8d0e740f77ff HTTP/1.1" 200 -
2020-01-18 17:14:08,487:wsdd INFO(pid 3097): 192.168.1.127 - - "POST /2e59ba01-7d42-5a44-a9ef-8d0e740f77ff HTTP/1.1" 200 -
2020-01-18 17:14:08,489:wsdd INFO(pid 3097): 192.168.1.121 - - "POST /2e59ba01-7d42-5a44-a9ef-8d0e740f77ff HTTP/1.1" 200 -
2020-01-18 17:14:08,490:wsdd INFO(pid 3097): 192.168.1.121 - - "POST /2e59ba01-7d42-5a44-a9ef-8d0e740f77ff HTTP/1.1" 200 -
```

which shows my other Windows 10 computers IP addresses.

but Windows refuses to connect [`Ubuntu is not accessible ... User name was not found`], so I must have done something wrong, or failed to do something needed.  I have tried many things, so I may have messed something up.

Comment: I think, the problem is `client max protocol = NT1`